# How to avoid vertical text going out of a table in LaTex?

Tags: tables, text, vertical

I am new to LaTex and I have a little problem with this table... I have to do a lot of tables of that kind and I would like to find a way to fix this issue automatically. Can someone help me please?
Below you find my code and the table.

Thanks a lot!

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
        \begin{center}
            \caption{Matrice de confusion pour les classes texturales concernant notre campagne d’échantillonnage.}
            \begin{tabular}{|
            >{\columncolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}c |
            >{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}c |c|c|c|c|}   
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Texture\\ observée sur le terrain\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
            \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} &  & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}A & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}L & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Z & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Total} \\ \cline{2-6} 
            \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & A & 3 & 2 & 0 & 5 \\ \cline{2-6} 
            \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & L & 4 & 7 & 0 & 11 \\ \cline{2-6} 
            \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & Z & 0 & 1 & 3 & 4 \\ \cline{2-6} 
            \multirow{-5}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Référence CNSW}}} & \textbf{Total} & 7 & 10 & 3 & \textbf{20} \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: The table]

Comment: well how would solve the issue if you would draw the table with a pen on a paper?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't really get what you mean.

Comment: The question is what layout you want. Should the font size shrink? Should the text be on two lines? Or do you want to increase the line spacing? Or do you want to shorten the text and write only "CNSW"? LaTeX can not design a table, that is your task.

Comment: Okay, I got what you mean ! Maybe it would be nice to write the text on two lines... But if you have another solution, I will take it !

Answer (score 4):

I would always try to avoid this excessive coloring of tables. Keep it clean and tidy, at the end that's more readable!

That said, here is one possible solution. Note that you have to manually fine-tune the `\parbox` position, though.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
        \caption{Matrice de confusion pour les classes texturales concernant notre campagne d’échantillonnage.}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}}
                \toprule
                    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\thead{Texture\\ observée sur le terrain}}\\
                \midrule
                \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[c]{2.2cm}{\centering\textbf{Référence CNSW}}}}
                    &  
                    & A 
                    & L 
                    & Z 
                    & \textbf{Total}\\
                    & A 
                    & 3 
                    & 2 
                    & 0 
                    & 5\\
                    & L 
                    & 4 
                    & 7 
                    & 0 
                    & 11\\
                    & Z 
                    & 0 
                    & 1 
                    & 3 
                    & 4\\\addlinespace
                    & \textbf{Total} 
                    & 7 
                    & 10 
                    & 3 
                    & \textbf{20} \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table]

Answer (score 4):

With `nicematrix`, you will have a perfect output in all the PDF viewers at all the levels of zoom (you won't have thin white lines in the grey panels and the rules won't seem to vanish at some levels of zoom).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\captionsetup{width=9cm, format=hang}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\caption{Matrice de confusion pour les classes texturales concernant notre campagne d’échantillonnage.}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccccc}[hvlines,corners=NW]
\CodeBefore
  \rectanglecolor{LightGrey!50}{2-2}{2-6} 
\Body
  & \Block[fill=LightGrey]{1-5}<\bfseries>{Texture\\ observée sur le terrain} \\ 
  \Block[fill=LightGrey]{5-1}<\bfseries\rotate>{Référence\\CNSW} & 
  \Block[fill=LightGrey!50]{5-1}{} 
  & A & L & Z & \textbf{Total} \\
  & A & 3 & 2 & 0 & 5 \\
  & L & 4 & 7 & 0 & 11 \\
  & Z & 0 & 1 & 3 & 4 \\
  & \textbf{Total} & 7 & 10 & 3 & \textbf{20} \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, with various improvements and code simplification. For your specific problem, the main tool is  the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks in standard cells, except it doesn't work well with colours in tables, because there are tabulars behind the scene. The `\Centerstack` command from `stackengine` does not have this problem. Also, you don't have to load `xcolor` and `colortbl`: the `table`option of xcolor does it for you, and it adds some more colour commands for tables. Last, `\cline` in a coloured table leaves some thin white lines, so I replaced them with `\hhline`s for which part of the lines have the colour of the background, so as to make them invisible .

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{grey2}{LightGrey!25}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption, makecell, hhline}
\newcommand{\myhhline}{\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{LightGrey}}- > {\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{grey2}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|----|}}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!ht]
        \centering
        \captionsetup{width=9cm, format=hang}
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
            \caption{Matrice de confusion pour les classes texturales concernant notre campagne d’échantillonnage.}
            \begin{tabular}{|
            >{\columncolor{LightGrey}}c |
            >{\columncolor{grey2}}c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{LightGrey} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\bfseries\Centerstack{Texture\\ observée sur le terrain}} \\ \hline
            \rowcolor{grey2}\cellcolor{LightGrey} & & A & L & Z & \textbf{Total} \\[-0.2pt]
            \myhhline
             & A & 3 & 2 & 0 & 5 \\[-0.1pt]
            \myhhline%
            & L & 4 & 7 & 0 & 11 \\[-0.1pt]
            \myhhline
            & Z & 0 & 1 & 3 & 4 \\[-0.1pt]
            \myhhline
            \multirow{-5}{*}{\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{\Centerstack{Référence\\ CNSW}}}} & \textbf{Total} & 7 & 10 & 3 & \textbf{20} \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]